# How do I dynamically change the sign of ggplot labels but not the underlying data?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am creating a population pyramid in ggplot and in order to get the bars to show correctly, I have changed the sign of one category to negative by multiplying the variable by -1.

The problem is now that I have the bars looking correctly but the axis labels show negative numbers. I am wondering how I change the sign dynamically (i.e. I cannot manually specify specific labels because the charts are being created in a loop and some will have different ranges). The code for the plot and an image are below.

Thank you

```
PyramidPlot <- ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data = PopEDMalesFullLessT, aes(x = Age, y = Percentage, fill = "red"), width= 0.4, 
           position = position_nudge(0.22), stat = "identity") +
  geom_bar(data = PopEDFemalesFullLessT, aes(x =  Age, y = Percentage, fill = "blue"), width= 0.4,
           position = position_nudge(0.22), stat = "identity") +
  scale_x_discrete(name = "Age Group")+
  labs(fill = "Legend") +
  theme_classic()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0.25, unit = "in")),
        axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(0.1, 0, 0.1, 0)),
        legend.position = c(0.9, 0.9)
  )+
  coord_flip()+
  scale_fill_discrete(labels=c('Males', 'Females'))
```

[image]

Comment: I'd also add that, for several years now, `geom_bar` and `geom_col` are smart enough if you give them one discrete and one continuous value to know which way to put the bar. So you can specify directly `geom_col(data = PopEDMalesFullLessT, aes(x = Percentage, y = Age, fill = "red"), width= 0.4,  position = position_nudge(0.22))` and not bother with `coord_flip()`. I always find it more straightforward in setting theme and labels when I don't have to remember the flip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give functions to the `labels` argument of a ggplot scale, in which case the function will be applied to the default labels. In this case, the absolute value function `abs` will work. See `?continuous_scale` for details and other options.

```
data.frame(x = 1:3, y = (-1):1) |> 
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = abs)
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thank you Gregor. Works perfectly